# What is the difference between a normal file download and a PHP-driven download?

Tags: php, download

Is there a difference between directly downloading a file from a web server, and downloading the same file through a PHP script that uses these headers?  (Assume that all of the variables here contain correct values for the file being downloaded.)

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: ' . $mimeType);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
```

After reading the discussion here, i want to change the question :

With a file on server for user who can download.

What & when do we need to process this task by PHP script?

Same question with direct link of file

Comment: Little offtopic - I think it is enough with `Content-Disposition` and `Content-Length` headers.

Comment: @binaryLV Disagree, if you don't set filename then some browsers will want to save as the last part of the URL (often having the wrong or no extension). Content-type may also be important but less so, as most OS's rely on file extension. Caching headers are essential for any content that is not downloaded (and even then...)

Comment: @Renesis, filename is specified by `Content-Disposition` header. About caching headers - I thought that caching must be *enabled* when necessary (rather than *disabled* when not necessary), though I'm not 100% sure about this.

Comment: @binaryLV Sorry, my mistake. As far as caching goes, that's actually what I meant. Though I think the default is actually somewhere in between (can cache for back/forward buttons at least, I think).

Comment: Default might vary from server to server. I'm using Apache+PHP for years, so I don't know about others. But if talking about Apache+PHP, then .css, .js, images etc (files that are meant to be static) seem to be cached by browser, .php (file that is meant to be dynamic by default) - reloaded on every page request even if it is used as a stylesheet (with `<link/>` tag) or as a javascript (with `<script/>` tag). At least that's what I see with firebug in FF. PHP-generated response lacks `Last-Modified`, `Etag` headers which might prevent it from being cached by default.

Comment: @binaryLV: as you said. if file is a static file. So cache is useful in this case ? What will happen if my file is always upgraded ?

Comment: @Chameron, is the file in question PHP or some other? If it is PHP file, then server probably assumes that it is not static and by default does not send headers that would tell browser that file should be cached.

Comment: @BinaryLV: oh, i am sorry, i have not exactly understood your comment. I were thinking about download file would be cached when provide direct link

Comment: Yeah, if file (not PHP) is accessed directly, then it may be cached. You can avoid this by either passing file through PHP script (like you do in your question), or maybe by configuring web server. I have never done this, but I think that it should be possible to modify headers with `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not as far as the client is concerned, no.

The difference for the server is that you have the full power of PHP to do something with before initiating the download, which is not the case if Apache handles the download directly. It also means that the whole cruft of PHP needs to be loaded and executed before a download can start and it'll occupy one PHP process until the download is finished.

Comment: if i only want to allow user download. Do not anything before and after download, so only give for user a direct link, don't need PHP code ? right ?

Comment: @Chameron Right. The only other reason would be if you have some really specific headers that you want to set or not set and can't get Apache to set them for you.

Answer (score 3):

***If*** your "normal" download would supply *those exact headers*, then ***no***.

However, a number of things could cause the server to decide to send different headers:

- If **[gzip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip#Other_uses)** is turned on (and browser accepts it)
- If the [request](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Requests) sent an **If-Modified-Since** header and the content has not been modified
- If the server decides to send a **Last-Modified** time
- If the server has some other sort of [cache-control logic](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html)

Comment: All this of course being configurable on the server as well, just maybe less direct than simply outputting the headers by hand.

Comment: @deceze True, though I'd say *much* less direct in the case of If-Modified-Since/304 stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I would think this would also let you create a download for a resource that is normally forbidden for a user to directly access. It also seems like you could use this for a file that only exists in memory, without having to write it out to disk first.

Comment: if resources are public, and store in server. And i don't want to do anything before and after download, so i only provide to user a direct link of file ? Are those some security error ?